# iOS screen translation

Tags: automation, iphone, ios

I want to quickly translate screen content on my iPhone. It would be great to translate it on the fly (like AR translation), but I don't think it's possible. I want to automate screenshot translation. I can run “command” by double tap on my iPhone back to make a screenshot and open the translation app. But I can't find how to pass screenshots to the app automatically. I want just double tap and see the result without any additional moves.

I need translate from Hebrew so I can't use standard application.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Google](https://google.com) Lens.

Take a screenshot of what you want to translate. Open your browser and go to [google.com](https://google.com). Click on the camera icon.

[image: Location of camera icon]

Upload your photo the way you like (drag-and-drop or upload). It should show the photo and the text detected will be highlighted in pale white. Click on Translate at the bottom of the page. And choose the original language in which the text is and the language in which you want it to be translated into.

[image: Choose language and actions]

You should see this; you can perform actions such as opening in Google Translate, copy text or play text out loud :

[image: Translated text]

Answer (score 1):

Note that this method does not work for Hebrew ([supported languages](https://www.apple.com/ios/feature-availability/#translate-translate-app)).

You just have to **select** (it will highlight in blue) the word/text you want to translate (preferably not too long or it will crash) by long-pressing on the word and dragging on a side or the other. Then, release your hold and click on the "**Translate**" option that should show up on top of the words selected. Now, it's quite self-explanatory but choose the options you want (original language and translation language) but it will most likely set it automatically.

[image]

What you should see when clicking on "Translate" :

[image]

### Edit : Translate built-in feature also works in Photos app if your iPhone supports Detect Live Text feature

Take a photo or screenshot of anything you want (with text), then open Photos app and click on the photo/screenshot you've just taken. Once this is done, click on the small "text" button [image] at the bottom-right-corner of the photo/screenshot. Once you have selected the text, it should show the options on top of it, click on "Translate" and choose the wanted options (already explained above).

From [Copy and translate text from photos on your iPhone or iPad](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212630) :

> To use Live Text, you need an iPhone XS, iPhone XR, or later with iOS 15 or later. [...] To use Live Text for video, you need iOS 16 or later or iPadOS 16 or later.

**Edit 2** : An extension to second method explained in the edit would be  :

1. Open **Translate app**
2. Under "Translation", click on **"Camera"**, it will ask you for authorisation to use the iPhone's camera, allow.
3. Then, **take a photo** of what you want to translate from Translate app, it should detect automatically the text in the picture.
4. Choose the **original language** of the picture text and the language you want to translate your photo to (**translation language**). You should see the translation on top (hiding) of the words in the picture.

[image: from https://apps.apple.com/us/app/translate/id1514844618]

**Note 1** : The solution listed in the edit is preferable because it can translate images (taken from a print, notebook, user manual, etc.) but the first solution is faster than anything I've found to translate text from a webpage or app.

**Note 2** : *The first method works with every **copy-able** text in any app.*

**Note 3** : All solutions listed above work perfectly for me, I find them useful since they use an Apple built-in feature and are easy to use.

**Note 4** : Translate feature comes with the [Translate app](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/translate/id1514844618) and is available on both iPad and iPhone.

To learn more about translating text, I suggest you read [this](https://support.apple.com/en-ie/guide/iphone/iphab4dcff1d/ios) Apple Support article.

Comment: You can also use [DeepL Translate](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/deepl-translate/id1552407475) with real time camera translations.

Answer (score 1):

#### [Use the Microsoft Translator App](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-translator/id1018949559)

It allows you to translate images both live via camera or from a saved photo.

I took a screen shot of a page from a Spanish Verb Conjugation eBook (Nook App) and submitted it to the Translator App. What I like about this App is that you don’t have to leave the Apple ecosystem/environment to accomplish this task.

**Original Image**

[image]

**Translated Image**

[image]